# Enviar datos post al redirigir con javascript

Tags: jquery, post, redirección

El formulario toma unos datos para obtener productos filtrados en una tienda online.

Si el formulario lleva **data-contenedor='#resultados_tienda'** la respuesta (productos) se tienen que pintar en el div con *id* #resultados_tienda.

Por el contrario si no lleva **data-contenedor** el formulario tiene que ser procesado en /tienda?proceso=be y los resultados se pintarán en esa otra url, esta url tiene este código que recoge los datos del $_POST y pinta en un contenedor ya definido:

```
// Búsqueda Externa des de otra página
else if (proceso == 'be')
{
    // Recogemos los datos POST
    var datos_post = <?=json_encode($_POST,JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS)?>;

    r_ajax( '/procesosajax_ec.php?proceso=ec_resultados_index&subproceso=buscador', 
            datos_post, 
            "#contenido_ajax", 
            'post',
            function(){goto_resultados()})
}
```

Por lo tanto tengo que hacer un proceso condicional:

- Si el formulario tiene data-contenedor pinto el resultado ajax en ese contenedor
- Si el formulario no tiene data-contenedor redirijo para que la url /tienda se encargue de procesar el formulario.

He probado usar .submit() o .trigger() para el segundo caso, pero se me produce un bucle.

El código Jquery iría contenido aquí:

```
    $(document.body).on( "submit", ".form_ec_buscador", function(ev) {

ev.preventDefault();

if (typeof modal_form_buscador_ec != 'undefined') {modal_form_buscador_ec.close();}

// Si hay contenedor, ejecutamos ajax y pontamos el resultado en él.
if ($(this).attr('data-contenedor'))
{
    // Si hay contenedor pintamos aquí, sino redirigimos a 
    // /tienda?proceso=be para que lo procese.
    var contenedor = $(this).data("contenedor");

    // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/procesosajax_ec.php?proceso=ec_resultados_index&subproceso=buscador',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("body").append ('<div class="espera"></div>');
        },                  
        // Mostramos un mensaje con la respuesta de PHP
        success: function(data) {

            $(".espera").remove();
            $("#" + contenedor).html(data);
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + contenedor).offset().top }, 1000);
        },
        error: function(){
            $(".espera").remove();
            swal("¡Error!", "Se ha producido un error.", "error"); 
        }
    });
}
else
{
    $(this).attr('action', '/tienda?proceso=be');
    $(this).submit();
}


    });
```

Y aquí dentro se trataría la condición anterior.

***HE ENCONTRADO ESTA SOLUCIÓN QUE PARECE FUNCIONAR***

Si tengo que hacer el submit, lo hago creando otro formulario con pocas líneas de código, fijaos en el *else* de este código, así no entro en bucle con el *submit* del formulario principal:

// Ejecuta el formulario de búsqueda/filtrado
// bien pinta el resultado o bien redirige a /tienda?proceso=be
// Todo depende de que se le haya indicado contenedor.
$(document.body).on( "submit", ".form_ec_buscador", function(ev) {

```
ev.preventDefault();

// Si hay contenedor, ejecutamos ajax y pontamos el resultado en él.
if ($(this).attr('data-contenedor'))
{
    if (typeof modal_form_buscador_ec != 'undefined') {modal_form_buscador_ec.close();}

    // Si hay contenedor pintamos aquí, sino redirigimos a 
    // /tienda?proceso=be para que lo procese.
    var contenedor = $(this).data("contenedor");

    // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/procesosajax_ec.php?proceso=ec_resultados_index&subproceso=buscador',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("body").append ('<div class="espera"></div>');
        },                  
        // Mostramos un mensaje con la respuesta de PHP
        success: function(data) {

            $(".espera").remove();
            $("#" + contenedor).html(data);
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + contenedor).offset().top }, 1000);
        },
        error: function(){
            $(".espera").remove();
            swal("¡Error!", "Se ha producido un error.", "error"); 
        }
    });
}
else 
{
    // Creamos un objeto formulario.
    var form = $('<form></form>');

    console.log('Hacemos envío del formulario a /tienda.');

    // Le añadimos el action y el método post
    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("action", '/tienda?proceso=be');

    // Del formulario lanzado, cogemos todos los campos y 
    // los añadimos al nuevo formulario.
    $.each( $(this).serializeArray(), function( indice, data ) 
    {
        var field = $('<input></input>');

        console.log('Campo: ' + indice);
        console.log('Nombre: ' + data.name);
        console.log('Valor: ' + data.value);

        field.attr("type", "hidden");
        field.attr("name", data.name);
        field.attr("value", data.value);

        form.append(field);
    });

    // Y ejecutamos un submit sobre el nuevo formulario.
    $(form).appendTo('body').submit();
}
```

});

Comment: agregastes ev.preventDefault()

Comment: Sí claro, para ver si el formulario tiene el atributo data-contenedor, no tengo más remedio que ejecutar un **ev.preventDefault()**

No funciona en el segundo caso:

_El formulario no tiene data-contenedor y tengo que ponerle un actión y hacer un submit_

Este es el código Jquery que se me ejecuta en bucle, no tengo manera de que el form haga un submit normal:

**No puedo ponerlo, no cabe.**

Comment: He añadido arriba el código que se ejecuta al intentar hacer un submit al formulario, fíjate en el _else_ ahí le pinto un _action_ al formulario e intento hacer el _submit_ pero evidentemente vuelve a ejecutar el código.

Comment: Este es el error que lanza la consola: *jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*
El código se ejecuta en bucle.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, gracias. Lo tienes aquí: https://pruebasphp.com/borrame.php
Y creo que lo he arreglado, redirige a la otra página pero tengo que ver si los resultados parten de los datos del formulario. Abre la consola. Pongo el código que he hecho arriba.

Comment: no agreges la respuesta en tu pregunta, dale click en publica tu respuesta